# How to set Amazon bucket policy using the Ruby SDK?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to set a bucket policy using the Ruby SDK like this:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-east-1')
obj = s3.bucket('my-bucket-name')
policy = AWS::S3::Policy.new
policy.allow(
  :actions => [:get_object],
  :resources => [obj],
  :principals => :any)

obj.policy = policy
obj.save!
```

But it doesn't seem to be saving. I've looked through the [ruby documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-ruby/) but it's not clear how to do this. I'd also like to be able to print out the current policies for the bucket if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following example. This allows you to set a policy and retrieve a policy (remember to change the bucket name and add credentials / change region if need be).

You may want to fine-grain the policy itself to restrict it to some object (folders and files are both objects). Remember that if you have an S3 layout such as my-bucket-name/folder/file and you wish to only restrict to that folder then it would be `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/folder/*` as the ARN.

Documentation for [setting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#put_bucket_policy-instance_method) and [getting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#get_bucket_policy-instance_method) policy.

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'json'

s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')

policy = {
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"]
    }
  ]
}

s3.put_bucket_policy({
  bucket: "my-bucket-name",
  policy: policy.to_json
})

 => #<struct Aws::EmptyStructure>

resp = s3.get_bucket_policy({
  bucket: "my-bucket-name",
})

resp.policy.read
 => "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"AddPerm\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"s3:GetObject\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*\"}]}"
```